# Allow specific directions for UIPopover

Tags: ios, objective-c, uipopovercontroller

I was wondering how do I do it if I want my UIPopoverConroller do show only either with the UIPopoverArrowDirectionLeft or UIPopoverArrowDirectionRight. I can get either all directions, or just one.

Is it possible to permit two?

Thanks

Comment: You mean show two arrows on the edge of a popover at the same time?

Comment: No, show only one, but allow only two directions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set permitted arrow directions as:

```
UIPopoverArrowDirectionLeft | UIPopoverArrowDirectionRight
```

The framework will then choose the best one to use when it presents the popover.

Comment: Works great, I was trying to use || at first which didn't work and led to me asking this question. This is, however great. Thanks

Comment: @DenisBalko `||` is the "logical or" operator. `|` is the "bitwise or" operator.